# How to create consistent API response class in ASP.NET Core 5 Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, .net-5

How would I create a consistent generic API response class in ASP.NET Core 5 Web API.

Basically I want to have a response from API just like

```
{
    Status Code : 200 or 404 
    Result Count : 1 (null or 0 in case of error or no data found)
    Response : [array of data (error message in case of error)]
}
```

I have created below sample class but it is useful only in case of success response. I am not able to use it in error scenario because the `Data` property is of `IEnumerable<T>` data type and I can not pass error message in string. Any help please?

Thanks in advance.

```
public class Result<T> 
{
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<T> Data { get; set; }
}

//sample code in controller
public IActionResult<IEnumerable<User>> GetAll()
{
    var list = _userRepository.GetAll();
    var model = new Result<User>
    {
        StatusCode = 200,
        Count = list.Count,
        Data = list
    };

    return Ok(model);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ApiResponse
    {
        public ApiResponse(int statusCode, string message = null)
        {
            StatusCode = statusCode;
            Message = message ?? GetDefaultMessageStatusCode(statusCode);
        }

        public int StatusCode { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }

         private string GetDefaultMessageStatusCode(int statusCode)
        {
            return statusCode switch {
                400 => "A bad request, you have made",
                401 => "Authorized, you are not",
                403 => "Forbidden from doing this, you are",
                404 => "Resource found, it was not",
                500 => "Errors are the path to the dark side. Errors lead to anger.  Anger leads to hate.  Hate leads to career change",
                _ => null
            };
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

for returning errors you have to do it like this

```
        var list = new List<string>()
        {
           "invalidata"
        };
        var model = new Result<string>
        {
            StatusCode = 400,
            Count = 0,
            Data = list
        };

        return BadRequest(model);
```

then you get response like this.

[image]